Evaluate expression inside custom class in polars
I am trying to extend the functionality of polars to manipulate categories of Enum. I am following this guide and this section of documentation
orig_df = pl.DataFrame({
    'idx': pl.int_range(5, eager=True),
    'orig_series': pl.Series(['Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma'], 
                dtype=pl.Enum(['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega']))})

@pl.api.register_expr_namespace('fct')
class CustomEnumMethodsCollection:
    def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
        self._expr = expr
    
    def rev(self) -> pl.Expr:
        cats = self._expr.cat.get_categories()
        tmp_sr = self._expr.cast(pl.Categorical)
        return tmp_sr.cast(dtype=pl.Enum(cats.str.reverse()))

(orig_df
    .with_columns(rev_series=pl.col("orig_series").fct.rev())
    )

This errors with TypeError: Series constructor called with unsupported type 'Expr' for the values parameter because cats is an unevaluated expression, not a list or a series, as pl.Enum(dtype=) expects it. How do I evaluate the cats into the actual list/series to provide the new categories for my cast(pl.Enum) method?

You can use .map_batches()
@pl.api.register_expr_namespace('fct')
class CustomEnumMethodsCollection:
    def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
        self._expr = expr
    
    def rev(self) -> pl.Expr:
        return self._expr.map_batches(lambda s:
            s.cast(pl.Enum(s.cat.get_categories().reverse()))
        )

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'idx': pl.int_range(5, eager=True),
    'orig_series': pl.Series(['Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma'], 
                   dtype=pl.Enum(['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega']))})

df.with_columns(rev_series=pl.col('orig_series').fct.rev()).schema

Schema([('idx', Int64),
        ('orig_series', Enum(categories=['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega'])),
        ('rev_series', Enum(categories=['Omega', 'Gamma', 'Beta', 'Alpha']))])


This looks to me  as a more "canonical" polars solution. Here .map_batches() provides both vectorization and context for evaluation (otherwise provided by .select() in the previous solution. Are there any performance penalties to .map_batches() approach or would you say it is always recommended in situations like this? Saw it also used in custom API examples.

Unless I am mistaken, map_batches is the only way to do this. Perhaps if https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/14293 was implemented pl.col("orig_series").reverse().cast(pl.Enum) could then just work. In my most recent testing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/79149719/) -  the use of map_batches added no performance penalty - but I'm not sure if we can say that is always the case.

You first got the categories (cats) of the orig_series column using .cat.get_categories(). This worked well. But then, you tried to convert this expression into a list using .to_list(). But an expression is just a "plan" for what Polars should compute. It doesn’t yet hold any actual values. Polars doesn't allow you to directly call .to_list() on an unevaluated expression.
So, you should do it this way:
import polars as pl

orig_df = pl.DataFrame({
    'idx': pl.int_range(5, eager=True),
    'orig_series': pl.Series(
        ['Alpha', 'Omega', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma'], 
        dtype=pl.Enum(['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega'])
    )
})

@pl.api.register_expr_namespace('fct')
class CustomEnumMethodsCollection:
    def __init__(self, expr: pl.Expr):
        self._expr = expr
    
    def rev(self) -> pl.Expr:
        cats = orig_df.select(self._expr.cat.get_categories()).to_series().to_list()
        reversed_cats = list(reversed(cats))
        return self._expr.cast(pl.Categorical).cast(dtype=pl.Enum(reversed_cats))

result_df = orig_df.with_columns(rev_series=pl.col("orig_series").fct.rev())
print(result_df)

Which gives
shape: (5, 3)
┌─────┬─────────────┬────────────┐
│ idx ┆ orig_series ┆ rev_series │
│ --- ┆ ---         ┆ ---        │
│ i64 ┆ enum        ┆ enum       │
╞═════╪═════════════╪════════════╡
│ 0   ┆ Alpha       ┆ Alpha      │
│ 1   ┆ Omega       ┆ Omega      │
│ 2   ┆ Alpha       ┆ Alpha      │
│ 3   ┆ Beta        ┆ Beta       │
│ 4   ┆ Gamma       ┆ Gamma      │
└─────┴─────────────┴────────────

Instead of treating cats as a raw expression, evaluate it using the select() method on orig_df, which tells Polars to actually compute the categories. After evaluation, the resulting categories are stored as a Series..to_list() is then called on the evaluated series, which gives you a python list of the actual category names ['Alpha', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Omega'].

Thank you for this! I was lacking evaluating context to actually "force" the evaluation of the expression. In your solution it has been provided by .select() I see that! Conversion all the way to list is unnecessary, because Enum categories can be successfully defined by pl.Series. Thank you again!
I wonder if there's a downside to forcing evaluation with .select(). In particular I am thinking of how this would function on LazyFrame.
